# awk find lines between two strings, one of which is variable

Tags: awk

I am trying to find the text between the two lines, the starting line contains an index(variable), so I need to pass it from shell to awk. But I am not able to figure out how to mix `/start/,/end/` construct with variables.

This is the input data:

```
echo "$x"
abc def 1
hey there
end

abc def 2
hello there
whats up
end

abc def 3
howdy
end
```

This works fine, but it is hard coding the index(Eg 2)

```
echo "$x" |awk '/abc def 2/,/end/'
abc def 2
hello there
whats up
end
```

Some naive attempts:

```
 -->echo "$x" |awk -vnum=2 '/abc def /2,/end/'
abc def 1
hey there
end

abc def 2
hello there
whats up
end

abc def 3
howdy
end

 -->echo "$x" |awk -vnum=2 'BEGIN{start="abc def "num}start,/end/'
abc def 1
hey there
end

abc def 2
hello there
whats up
end

abc def 3
howdy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown attempts, please try following `awk` code. This is one way of passing `awk` variable value to search range. Using `match` function of `awk` and matching string with variable till string end(taken from OP's attempts here) to Print matched lines.

```
echo "$x" | awk -v val="2" 'match($0,"abc def " val"$"),/end/'
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a variable like this:

```sh
echo "$x" | awk -vnum=2 '$0 ~ "abc def " num,/end/'

abc def 2
hello there
whats up
end
```

If `abc` and `end` markers must comprise complete line then better to use anchors:

```sh
echo "$x" | awk -vnum=2 '$0 ~ "^abc def " num "$",/^end$/'
```

This will avoid matching line with string `abc def 20`

Answer (score 2):

If you really have two `\n\n` between blocks you can use [paragraph mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html) and match the first field:

```
echo "$x" | awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' -v mark="2" 'match("^abc def " mark "$", $1)'
abc def 2
hello there
whats up
end
```

You *could* also use `sed` here with double quotes to allow the mark variable to be expanded by the shell:

```
mark=2
echo "$x" | sed -n "/^abc def ${mark}$/,/^end$/p"
```

Comment: Thanks, for mentioning `sed` , this is rather simple with `sed`